# Multiselect onChange event not working when load data in primeng version 7.0.5

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to do some stuff when data inside multiselect is changed(selected), but when I try to load selected items to multiselect by click on button, 'onChange' event not working. I can`t understand why. Check it please on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-primeng)

Comment: Your component is triggering the change, not the PrimeNG MultipleSelect. Therefore it shouldn't be responsible for changes happening outside its "jurisdiction" so-to-speak

Comment: When you click the Load button, you're updating the `loadOptions` array (the variable that represents the selected items), but the values you're passing in don't match up with the values in your `options` array. You need to update you `options` array with the new SelectItems you want in there

Comment: Sorry, maybe I give bad explanation, I don`t need new SelectItems, I need select some of existing by click on 'Load'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to completely load in new possible options, and not just auto-select options with your button-click, then you have to update your initial `options` array with new `SelectItem`s, like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-primeng-apqng7?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

```
load() {
    this.options = [
      { label: 'Geometry', value: 'Geometry' },
      { label: 'Physics', value: 'Physics' },
      { label: 'Chemistry', value: 'Chemistry' },
    ];
}
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to *select* options when clicking Load, you'd need to set your `loadOptions` array to contain existing values (not new ones), like this:

```
load() {
    this.loadOptions = ['Aerospace'];
}
```

You could combine these as well if you're trying to update all possible options **and** select one or more of them.

Also, the `onChange` method is working. I think you may be expecting it to fire at the wrong time though. `onChange` fires when the *selection* value changes, not when the *options* change. If you select/deselect values in your component, you can see your console log is printing as expected.

Comment: How can I trigger onChange event when I load selected data to multiselect?

Comment: onChange doesn't fire then. You could however, add a setter function on your `options` property like `set options(value) { this._options = value; /* handle other stuff here */ }` (you'll also need a `get options() { return this._options; }` as well then.)